# how do i set up task scheduler to shred a specific folder?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have a folder of important information I don't want people to have access to but I don't want to get rid of it right now.

what I want is to set up a task to have it shredded using glary utilities in the event I don't shut off the task.

Glary utilities has a separate file for the shredder application so I'm pretty sure windows can open that part of the program its just setting it up that I have no clue how to do. I clicked create task to see what I could do but I can't find anything in there that would help me.

Comment: I have Glary Utilities here.  So far as I can see with some reasonable research is that there is not a command line option for the Glary programs.

Comment: what about just deleting the folder in general. not using glary utilities to shred it. i prefer to shred everything i delete just because i think its safer overall but if theres no command for it then theres no command.

Comment: This approach has a fundamental weakness: your time bomb works only with the assumption that anybody can boot your computer and log in so the scheduled task is triggered. Under these assumptions the file or directory in question is very easy to pull off the computer without triggering the time bomb. Why not do it properly and keep the file encrypted at all times?